# Sankey diagram onmouseover

Tags: google-visualization, onmouseover, sankey-diagram

I am having difficulties to use onmouseover event on a sankey diagram that I am creating as a visualization example. I am able to add the event and show a static alert, but I want to show the value of the link selected possible on the selected link.

```
    var chart = new    google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_basic'));               
    chart.draw(data, options);  
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', showData);
```

and the function

```
function showData(e)
{

     var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_basic'));
    alert(chart.Rows(e.column["Weight"]));       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use d3.js sankey it will give you the totals in the bands and nodes as per this example...http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c9b90689c1438f57d649